# Apache RewriteCond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewritecond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(css|js)$
```

Which works great and takes care of requests like:

`http://domain.com/js/script.js` and `http://domain.com/css/stylesheet.css`

However I would like to exclude if the pattern is:

`http://domain.com/projects/{varname}/{varname}/download/{varname}/{varname}.js`

or

`http://domain.com/projects/{varname}/{varname}/download/{varname}/{varname}.css`

Where `{varname}` can be anything.

Is it possible to change my RewiteCond in a way so that the downloads are excluded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add another `RewriteCond` before the current:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\/download\/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(css|js)$
RewriteRule ....
```

Hope the helps.

Comment: I tried also the rule about css/js and it worked but after that I get 404.Any idea why this might happening?